# TypeError while fetching the user profile in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[error log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqkg5.png) I have been facing this problem which is not working for me at the moment

I basically have an auth app that I am able to register and login however When I am trying to fetch the profile data I am facing a TypeError( Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined.

In the redux tool

```
the isAuthenticated: true
error: null
and profile: {
joined: xxxxxx
_id:4rt43dfdsletc
firstName: "xxxx"
email:"adfadf@fsa.com"
}
```

etc, everything is working and also the app includes the redux persist which is working also

However, in the Navbar, I am trying to display the user FirstName and I am getting the error

Here is my LOGIN.ACTION.JS

```
export const autUser = data => {
  return async dispatch => {
    // dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST}
    return await apiLogin(data)
      .then(res => {
        const token = res.data.token;
        console.log(token);
        dispatch(success(token));
        setAuthHeader(token);
        dispatch(getUserProfile())
        // console.log('User Details', jwt.decode(token));
      })
//error will be dispatched here
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};


const success = token => {
  localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_NAME, token);
  return { type: LOGIN_SUCCESS };
};

const error = error => {
  return { type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error };
};
```

FETCH PROFILE within the same file

```
export const getUserProfile = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            console.log("fetching profile......")
            const { data : {user} } = await apiFetchProfile();
            dispatch({ type: PROFILE_FETCHED, payload: user })
            console.log(user)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    };
};
```

here is my index.js

```
store.dispatch(checkLoggedIn())
if(localStorage.donedeal){
    setAuthHeader(localStorage.donedeal);
    store.dispatch(getUserProfile())
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store ={store}>

<App />
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./navbar.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logOut} from "../../actions/login";
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import logo  from './logo.png'
const Navbar = ({ isAuth, logOut, profile}) => {
  return (
    <header>

        <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className="logo" />
         <nav className="nav_links">
             <li><p> Buy and sell <span className="bold"> your things  </span> </p></li>
             <a className="cta" href=""><button> <li className="fas fa-plus"></li> Place ad </button></a>
             {/* <li><a href=""> Sign up</a></li> */}
       {/* <li><a href=""> Login</a></li> */}
       {isAuth ? (
         <div>
           <p>{profile.firstName}</p>

           <button onClick={() => logOut()}> Logout </button>
         </div>

          ) : (<div><button> Login </button><button>Register</button></div>) 
          }
         </nav>




    </header>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ login }) => {
  return {
    isAuth: login.isAuthenticated,
    profile: login.profile
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logOut}
)(Navbar);
```

The above code is all over the place that's because I am just experimenting with it but it's registering and log in the user and even fetching the profile but I can't display the information.

There could a type or something that I have done wrong in which I cant see

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is `login.isAuthenticated ` initialized to `false` in initial state? If so, when it is changed to `true`. Is it possible that `isAuth` is true and your `profile` is still no loaded?

Comment: the  isAuthenticated  is  false  ineed when the state at init
Everything seems to work fine,  the data is persisted to local storage
the profile is loaded and persisted

But I could not find way of getting it to work

I tried to trace this error and I want to see what is causing it but no luck so far

Comment: Yes, it seems all right. Can you create code sandbox containing the problem situation?

Comment: the following changes did the job
in the authAction, after getting the data, I set the authHeader(token)
then I called the Profile action then I returned success in case of login

     setAuthHeader(token);
      dispatch(getUserProfile());
      dispatch(success(token));

Comment: I deleted the DB and registered new details and it worked

How can I post the working code, just in case someone might use it
thanks

Comment: Also, I created an action that checks if the token is found localStorage as follows:

 `try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME);
      if (token === null || token === "undefined") {
        return dispatch(error("You need to login "));
      }
      setAuthHeader(token);
      dispatch(getUserProfile());
      dispatch(success(token));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }`

Comment: then I called it in index.js where the app starts
So basically what I realized is that the profile is fetched when the user is signin...
then when the page reloads it's not called fetched again thus I get firstName is not definded

Comment: Great, if you've found solution for your problem, post it here as an answer, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the above problem(Code could be improve as well)

AuthAction
calls the apiLogin(axios)
then it returns the data
then we set the header
and we call the profileAction and we dispatch success and errors(not implemented yet)

```
export const signIn = request_data => {
  console.log('Authenticating action is called ....................')
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const {
        data: { token }
      } = await apiLogin(request_data);
      setAuthHeader(token);
      dispatch(getUserProfile());
      dispatch(success(token));
    } catch (e) {
      const {
        response: { data }
      } = e;
      dispatch(error(data.error));
    }
  };
};
```

getUserProfile

```
export const getUserProfile = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
      console.log('Fetching User profile....................')
      try {
        const {
          data: { user }
        } = await apiFetchProfile();

        dispatch({ type: PROFILE_FETCHED, payload: user });
        console.log(user)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
  };

const success = token => {
  localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_NAME, token);
  return { type: AUTH_SUCCESS };
};
const error = error => {
  return { type: AUTH_FAILED, payload: error };
};
```

authReducer.js

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuth: false,
    profile: {},
    error: null
  };

  export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case AUTH_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, isAuth: true, error: null };
      case AUTH_FAILED:
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuth: false,
          error: action.payload
        };
      case USER_LOGGED_OUT:
        return { ...state, isAuth: false, profile: {} };
      case PROFILE_FETCHED:
        return { ...state, profile: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

export const checkToken = () => {
  console.log('Checking LStorage is called ....................')
  return dispatch => {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME);
      if (token === null || token === "undefined") {
        return dispatch(error("You need to login "));
      }
      setAuthHeader(token);
      dispatch(getUserProfile());
      dispatch(success(token));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
};
```

index.js

```
import  {checkToken} from './actions/auth_actions'
import store from './store'
// import setAuthHeader from './api/setAuthHeader'
// import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';



store.dispatch(checkToken());


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store ={store}>

<App />
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

These are the changes that I made and it working now
Now I have to handle errors

so basically, the SignIn actions call the backend API, it returns the token, then we send the authHeader and while doing that I call the getUserProfile and it calls the backend and gets the user profile
Then I created an action that will be called in the index.js at the start of the application and so that if the user reloads the page we dispatch the user profile again and that was the problem

Hope this helps somebody